# Update PHP to latest version from source

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, php5, xubuntu

I am currently running PHP 5.4.6-1ubuntu1.1 (CLI) (built: Nov 15 2012 01:18:34) on Xubuntu. I would like to update to the latest version or >= 5.4.7. Is there another way to do this instead of compiling it from the source? If source is the only solution, can you please guide me in how to do it painlessly.

UPDATE: I did this:

[Upgrading PHP from version 5.3 to 5.4.7](https://serverfault.com/questions/431805/upgrading-php-from-php-5-3-to-5-4-7) and http://wiki.helioviewer.org/wiki/Compiling_PHP_from_source_on_Ubuntu

Now from CLI it shows as 5.4.12, but from Apache it is still 5.4.6. Any ideas how to make Apache use the new installation of PHP?

Comment: Which version of Xubuntu are you using?

Comment: @Tonin Ubuntu 12.10

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for updated PHP packages, you might want to look at [dotdeb](http://www.dotdeb.org) which is a well maintained repository containing the latest PHP binaries.  However, it is targeted at Debian, so you'll need to see how well it is working with your Ubuntu version.

This [other question on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109404/how-do-i-install-php-5-4-0) also gives some pointers to some PPA containing updated PHP5 packages.

As for your compiled PHP 5.4.12 not used by apache, you probably need to tell apache which mod_php to use (the new one and not the Ubuntu provided one).  Look at your apache configuration for instructions like `LoadModule php5_module` and see if it points at the newest one.